# Cucumber Steps for JQuery DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, cucumber, jquery-ui-datepicker

My page has a JQuery UI DatePicker on an input field #my_date.

I can launch the DatePicker using :

```
page.execute_script %Q{ $('#my_date').trigger("focus") }
```

How can I write a step for selecting a particular date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using :

```
page.execute_script %Q{ $("a.ui-state-default:contains('17')").trigger("click") }
```

Where **17** is the day of the current month to be selected, in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't feel an acceptance test of datepicker is needed; I just use the field set method

```
find(:css, ".my_date-alt").set '12/31/1999'
```